# Angular - Firebase - Repeating DIV ng-repeat duplicating new rows

Tags: angularjs, firebase

In running into a problem where I have a repeating DIV on my page, but I am getting duplicates when I add new rows.  So for example if I have Row A and and Row B, and then I click "Add" to add a new row, I would like to see 3 rows.  However I get 5 rows, Row A, Row B, then Row A, Row B and the new Row C.

The page initializes fine, will display only the 3 rows, but what am I doing wrong with the "Add" of new rows...It appears to be not refreshing as I would like?

Any help would be great!
Thanks!

My ng-repeat looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="infant in Infants" class="list card">
    <h2>{{infant.name}} - {{infant.ID}}</h2>
    <a class="item item-icon-left assertive" href="#"> <i class="icon ion-ios-analytics"></i> Last measurement 188mm / 190mm (size 5.5) </a>
</div>
```

The initialisation of **Infants** above is achieved with a global array:

```
$scope.Infants = [];

...

    if (firebaseUser) {
        //set the user and infant list variables
        $log.log("Signed in as:", firebaseUser.uid);
        var usersRef = firebase.database().ref('users');
        loggedInUser = usersRef.child(firebaseUser.uid);
        loggedInUser.on('value', snapshot => {
            $log.log("UserDetails:", snapshot.val());
        });
        InfantList = loggedInUser.child('infantList');
        InfantList.on('value', snapshot => {
            $log.log("InfantDetails:", snapshot.val());
            angular.forEach(snapshot.val(), function (value, key) {
                $log.log("val", value);
                $log.log("key", key);
                $scope.Infants.push(value);
            });
        });
     }
```

Then the function call when the ""Add" button is clicked looks like this:

```
$scope.AddProfile = function () {
    // get the firebase location
    var newInfantRef = firebase.database().ref('/users/' + firebaseUser.uid + '/infantList/');
    // create the element
    var newRef = newInfantRef.push();
    //add attributes
    var newItem = {
        riskLevel: '1.0'
        , ID: newRef.key
        , name: "Reggie"
        , gender: "M"
        , DOB: "2015-02-01"
    };
    // Write the new infant.
    var newInfant = {};
    newInfant['/' + newRef.key + '/'] = newItem;
    newInfantRef.update(newInfant);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your InfantList.on() you are pushing again all values to the array when a new value is added.

To solve this try:

```
    InfantList.on('child_added', snapshot => {
           ...your things...
    }
```

This only push the new value to the array when the new value is added.

Comment: Thanks Gerard!... do you mean add to the "AddProfile" function?

Comment: Note that you were listening for value changes on the full InfantList node and its children and then iterating through all of them to obtain their values (and causing the duplicate problem), if you do as Gerard proposed and use an on child-added listener you have to take care of two things:
- Now every time the listener triggers it will contain the child node itself, so you don't have to iterate over it
- Value changes in children will not trigger the listener, to do this you need a [child-changed](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events) event

Comment: Ahh.. i got you.  God there's a lot i don't know here!  I fixed it by adding the line: $scope.Infants = []; after the line "InfantList.on('value', snapshot => {"  reinitialising the array